# passing a multidimensional array from one activity to another

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

How can I pass a multidimensional array from one activity to another?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Serializable` class which wraps the two-dimensional array, and pass it using `Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable value)`

Comment: I have to pass a 2-d string array. Can u please give some example of how to pass and retrieve the array using Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable value)

Comment: To build on what codelark said, you'd create a new class which implements the standard java.io.Serializable interface and then implement writeObject() and readObject() to send your Strings to & from the ObjectOutputStream. Once you have that class you can put instances of it into an Intent.

Comment: Of course, if you have thousands of strings this might be too slow. You could implement your own scheme to condense your array to a single String (e.g. joining the elements together with some character sequence that's guaranteed to not appear in the array content).

Comment: If you're passing thousands of strings, using any of the persistance strategies and passing the id to retrieve them would be a less-crazy thing to do.